# Can Ubuntu Touch be install from other Ubuntu flavors?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, phone

The way to install Ubuntu Touch on a phone is to use Ubuntu desktop.

Can I install Ubuntu Touch on the phone using a different Ubuntu flavor like Kubuntu and Xubuntu?

Comment: Which guide are you referring to? What makes you think this would only work from standard Ubuntu desktop?

Comment: Yes, you can. Even from Windows. Only prerequisite is the android sdk, aka. fastboot and adb.

Answer (score 4):

Basically you are just flashing a new ROM to your phone and then install it with a bootmanager on your phone.

You can flash the ubuntu touch ROM from any system you want. All you need is a tool for flashing the ROM to your phone (copying the image to the phone to speak easy).

The Android SDK, with adb and fastboot, is convinient for this task and available for all major plattforms (Linux, Windows, Mac).

So, to answer your question, yes, you can flash ubuntu touch from any OS or ubuntu flavor to your phone with the Android SDK, but to install you need your phone to be unlocked and a bootmanger installed that is capable to install an recovery image.